# Histogram and range filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram

I want to aggregation histogram result with Elasticsearch, but filtering with date range. This is my body request:

```
body: {
        query:{
            bool:{
                must:{
                    match:{
                        campaignId: req.params.id
                    },
                    filter:{
                        range:{
                            createdAt:{
                                gte: req.query.date1,
                                lt : req.query.date2,
                                format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        aggs:{
            created_by_day:{
                date_histogram: {
                    field: "createdAt",
                    interval: "day",
                    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
                }
            }
        }
```

This body request, return me no aggregations. Only the documents that match with the `ID` and the range date `createdAt`.

If I remove the filter range part, the histogram aggregations works correctly, but I need to filter for a specified dates.

Comment: It means there are no records between that specified range.

Comment: @Richa if I remove the `agg` part, ths histogram works correctly

Comment: How can you use histogram after removing `agg` part???

Comment: The histogram daesn't appear, but I can see results between the range, that means that there ara records. I 'solved' meanwhile doing the histogram manualy; with an aggregation range